# Visual Studio 2015 Typescript auto list members stopped working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm working on an Angular2 project; all of a sudden the auto list members for typescript files stopped working. Obviously I realized that after a while and I'm not able to say what caused the problem.

I tried the uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio, with no result. 
I'd say it's not some project configuration, because opening the same solution on a brand new installation of Visual Studio on another laptop, intellisense works perfectly.

The version of Visual Studio is 2015 update 3. The version of typescript is 2.1.4.

Is there some kind of log file I could read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, this issue appears recently, did you install any update under windows update or VS install any extensions or updates? If so, you can try to remove them one by one to locate this issue.

Since this same solution works fine in another VS and laptop, this issue should have caused by the VS or computer which has this issue, you can have a try the following to troubleshot this issue:

1. Run VS using different commands, open an administrative CMD window and navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and run the commands as below:

•   devenv /resetuserdata: clean up the old user data

•   devenv /resetsettings: reset the customized setting to the default 
setting, if you want to keep the current setting, you need to export it before resetting it, please go to Tool-Import and Export Settings…

After each command, reopen VS and check it again.

2. Perform a clean boot follow the steps from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135 then re-run the VS as administrator and check this issue again.

**[Edit]**

The workaround from Gio: Finally I fixed that! Just replaced the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript" folder with the one on the working laptop.

Comment: I had already tried the resetuserdata, and now the resetuserdata didnt' make the trick.

Comment: I guess I found something analyzing the differences between the extensions lists of my laptop and the one with the working installation: my VS has installed (in the SDK section), the "Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript". Looking on the web it seems to be for the 2013 VS and should influence the intellisense's work, but I couldn't find a way to remove it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry Sara, in the first comment I meant that the resetsettings didn't make the trick! I also tried the clean boot, with no effect.

Comment: Finally I fixed that! Just replaced the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript" folder with the one on the working laptop. I really don't know what happened, because I installed typescript 2.1.4 on both the machines, nothing more, nothing less. Anyway, thanks for your hints, it help me looking after the extensions direction.

Comment: @Gio, thank you for your sharing, I will update your useful solution into my previous reply, in case some community members who have the same or similar issue to easier search this workaround.